# android activity which never close, pop-up

Tags: android, android-activity, popup

Is an Android activity possible that is impossible to close?

For example, when button start is pressed and some process starts that activity won't be closed in any way until everything is finished.

Also, how to make an activity which pops-up when button (device button, not on application) to go back is pressed?

Comment: Seems like extremely bad practise to me. If what you are trying to do is ensure your process is not killed before it finishes its work, you could have a look at the Services, and do your calculations in a foreground service. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29

Answer (score 0):

that is not possible because the home button will always get you out of an activity no matter what not te mention the user can always end your app

Answer (score 0):

No-  the user can always force close the app through Android settings (or a task killer).  Also, the framework will kill you whenever it decides it needs your memory.

For your second thing-  if your app is in the foreground you can override what the back button does via onBackPressed.  That's how you'd do things like pop up a save dialog.  But you can't catch presses to that button unless you're the foreground activity (or in some cases, the keyboard).